# How to temporarily store data with jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, storage

I have one problem and since I am not very skilled with js, I would appreciate any advice.

Basically, I have an ajax call on article page executed every x seconds, that connects to database and checks for the comment number.

Now, after every call, I need to check if the last call returned number bigger than the previous call (to check if the number comments has increased).

I am having trouble figuring out how to properly store data of the single call that will be deleted after comparison with the next call, and of course overwritten by the new data.

Now, there are two methods that I could use and know how to: cookies and storing data in dom inside of the invisible element, but is that optimal solution?

Comment: You should show the code you've come up with so far. FYI, since it's just AJAX over and over, you can just hold the data in a JS var...

Comment: Thanks JAAulde, I accepeted answer below but your comment is correct to, thanks :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you dont need to use cookies or dom to store this data. Just use closures*!

```
var old = null;

$.get(url, function(d){
   if(old == null){
     old = d;
   }
   if(old.something > d.something){
      //do something else
   }
});
```

Closures are the reason why this works, if javascript did not have them you would not be able to modify the outer `old` var in the `$.get` function.

Comment: Thnaks, for some reason I feared that the variable cleans up itself on every ajax call execution. It was actually very simple :)

Answer (score 2):

Use a variable that is outside of the scope of your comment getting/rendering functions:

```
var CommentsModule = (function(){
    var me = {},
        numComments = null;

    function renderComments(comments){
        //render logic here
        for(i=numComments || 0; i<comments.length;i++){ //the || 0 handles the initial load when the numComments === null
            //append new comments
        }
        //reset your 'cached' variable to the current # of comments
        numComments = comments.length;
    }

    me.getComments = function() {
        //do $.get or $.ajax
        $.ajax("myURL",
            success: function(msg) { 
                if(msg.length > numComments) {
                    renderComments(msg);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    return me;
}());
```

In your page:

```
setInterval(CommentsModule.getComments, 5000);
//....or something
```

Comment: Thanks, I accepetd above answer as it was posted before, but this is correct and I went with such solution.

Answer (score 1):

Localstorage:

```
localStorage.setItem('lastUpdate','2013-02-04');

var lastUpdate = localStorage.getItem('lastUpdate');
```

or use the data attribute of your comments, e.g:

```
$('#comments').data('lastUpdate', '2013-02-04');
```

Answer (score 0):

The two methods you mentioned are correct - I'd typically store data in the DOM inside an invisible element.

Three more that you may want to look into:

1) Modern browsers now have HTML5 local storage, which is functionally the equivalent of a cookie, except it's stored in browser storage. This doesn't exist in IE9, and is still developing in modern browsers, so don't use this unless you know the user's browser has this (IE9 doesn't support it yet). http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

2) If you're using jQuery, there's jQuery data: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/, which allows you to attach data to specific elements. That link explains it better than I can here.

3) Depending on how your javascript is set up, can you simply store the number of previous comments in a variable in the javascript? Then, when your AJAX call returns, you can compare the result variable vs. the previous count variable. I'd opt for this solution if possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code. It need JQuery for cookie plugin. It is not for temporary storage.

```
    function GetData(key)
    {
        var sonuc = "";
        if (typeof (localStorage)!="undefined")
        {
            //İkinci html5 localStorage desteği varmı ona bakılır
            if (localStorage[key] != null)
            {
                sonuc= localStorage[key];
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //son olarak cookie desteği varmı ona bakılır
            sonuc=$.cookie(key);
        }
        return sonuc;
    }

    function SetData(key,value)
    {
        if (typeof (localStorage) != "undefined")
        {
            //ikinci önce html5 localStorage desteği varmı ona bakılır
            try
            {
                localStorage.setItem(key, value);
                return true;
            } catch (e)
            {
                return false;
            }

        }
        else
        {
            //son olarak cookie desteği varmı ona bakılır
            try
            {
                $.cookie(key, value);
                return true;
            } catch (e)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    /*this plugin is to add cookie function to jquery*/
    /*Copyright (c) 2006 Klaus Hartl (stilbuero.de)*/
    jQuery.cookie = function (name, value, options) {
        if (typeof value != 'undefined') { // name and value given, set cookie
            options = options || {};
            if (value === null) {
                value = '';
                options.expires = -1;
            }
            var expires = '';
            if (options.expires && (typeof options.expires == 'number' || options.expires.toUTCString)) {
                var date;
                if (typeof options.expires == 'number') {
                    date = new Date();
                    date.setTime(date.getTime() + (options.expires * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
                } else {
                    date = options.expires;
                }
                expires = '; expires=' + date.toUTCString(); // use expires attribute, max-age is not supported by IE
            }
            var path = options.path ? '; path=' + (options.path) : '';
            var domain = options.domain ? '; domain=' + (options.domain) : '';
            var secure = options.secure ? '; secure' : '';
            document.cookie = [name, '=', encodeURIComponent(value), expires, path, domain, secure].join('');
        } else { // only name given, get cookie
            var cookieValue = null;
            if (document.cookie && document.cookie != '') {
                var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
                for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
                    var cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);
                    // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
                    if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) == (name + '=')) {
                        cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            return cookieValue;
        }
    };
    /*end of jquery plugin*/
```